Typescript incompatible after Prisma request
Hi I am struggling getting Typescript to work with my current setup.  For reference this is cut down version of my prisma Model.
model Invoice {
  id              String    @id @default(uuid())
  invoiceNumber   String?

  clientId String?
  client   Client? @relation(fields: [clientId], references: [id])

  companySettings CompanySettings @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id])
  companyId       String

  lineItems InvoiceLineItem[]

  userId String
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

model InvoiceLineItem {
  id              String  @id @default(uuid())
  itemName        String?
  invoice         Invoice @relation(fields: [invoiceId], references: [id])
  invoiceId       String
}

model Client {
  id           String    @id @default(uuid())
  name         String    @unique @db.VarChar(256)
  user         User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId       String    @db.VarChar(256)
  invoices     Invoice[]
}

So a Client can have many invoices.  An Invoice can have many lineItems.  So I tried replicating this as an interface
export interface InvoiceLineItem {
  id: string;
  itemName?: string | null;
  invoiceId: string;
}

export interface Invoice {
  id: string;
  invoiceNumber?: string | null;
  clientId?: string | null;
  companyId: string;
  lineItems?: InvoiceLineItem[];
  userId: string;
}

export interface Client {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  userId: string;
  invoices?: Invoice[];
}

So I want to retrieve all clients so I have the following
export const fetchClients = async (): Promise<Client[] | null> => {
  try {
    const clientsRes = await GetClients();
    if (clientsRes.success && clientsRes.clients) {
      return clientsRes.clients;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
};

Whats returned is something like this
[
  {
    id: '70414b0a-a9f2-400f-8c88-e57cb9ca2050',
    name: 'Test client',
    creationDate: 2024-06-03T14:40:00.181Z,
    userId: 'asdasd',
    invoices: []
  }
]

Now at this point its one client, with no invoices, hence no lineItems.  But I would have thought an empty lineItems array would be included in the response as my action is this
 const clients = await db.client.findMany({
      where: {
        userId: user.id ? { equals: user.id } : undefined,
      },
      include: {
        invoices: {
          include: {
            lineItems: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });

And I think thats where fetchClients is complaining, more specifically return clientsRes.clients; I get
Type '({ invoices: ({ lineItems: { id: string; itemName: string | null; invoiceId: string; }[]; } & { ...; })[]; } & { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Client[]'.
    Types of property 'invoices' are incompatible.
      Type '({ lineItems: { id: string; itemName: string | null; invoiceId: string; }[]; } & { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Invoice[]'.

Am I missing something here?  Is it complaining due to not having lineItems in the response?  Sorry, first time using Typescript to trying to fully understand things.
Thanks

The Client type by default does not include information about relational models that are attached to Client. So if you are using the Client type exported by Prisma, that will omit the invoices property.
If you want to generate a Prisma type for Client that includes all those relational types, you should use the Prisma validator to generate the arguments for the query ahead of time, then emit the corresponding type which can be reused outside of that specific query by getting the corresponding payload.
Write out your query using the Prisma validator like this:
const clientWithInvoicesArgs = Prisma.validator<Prisma.ClientArgs>()({
  include: {
    invoices: {
      include: {
        lineItems: true,
      },
    },
  }
});

export type ClientWithInvoicesAndLineItems = Prisma.ClientGetPayload<
  typeof clientWithInvoicesArgs
>;

// Use it in your Prisma query like this
const clients = await prisma.client.findMany({
  include: clientWithInvoicesArgs.include
});

You can then reuse clientWithInvoicesArgs for your Prisma queries and ClientWithInvoicesAndLineItems for functions/components that rely on the specific shape of this data. You can replace Client[] with ClientWithInvoicesAndLineItems[] in your fetchClients function.
